# Rails query association AND

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an `User` model with a HABTM association with `Tag` model. I need all `users` who necessarily have all conditions, not just one.

Ex:

```
User.includes(:tags).where(tags: { id: [2,3,...] })
```

Returns `users` who have `tags` with id 2 and / or 3, but I would like to only return `users` who have `tags` with ids 2 AND 3.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of this option:

```
User.includes(:tags).where(tags: { id: 2 }).where(tags: { id: 3 })
```

If you have a severals `tag_ids`, and if the intermediate table between user and tags is `user_tags`

```
tag_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
where = tag_ids.map do |id|
    "tags.id = #{id}"
end.join(" AND ")

puts where # "tags.id = 1 AND tags.id = 2 AND tags.id = 3 AND tags.id = 4 AND tags.id = 5"

User.joins("INNER JOIN user_tags ON user_tags.user_id = user.id INNER JOIN tags ON tags.id = user_tags.tag_id").where(where)
```

If you wish to continue using the `includes`, there is no other choice that continue using the where in the rails-ish way.

Comment: What if there are 100 `tags.id`s?

Comment: Which is the intermediate table?

Comment: @m.simonborg I had update the question regarding the 100 `tags.id`s

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
user_ids = Tag.where(id: [2,3]).pluck(:user_id).uniq
User.where(id: user_id)
```

`pluck` won't instantiate all the tag objects, so while this may not be ideal, it should at least be pretty quick.

Comment: Despite the fact that the tag objects are not instantiated, the disadvantage of this is that you are doing two queries instead of one.